Multi-longitudinal laser modes
I have a cavity which emits a laser beam, characterized by a number of modes, let say 400, with a total power P which can be for example 10 W. I'm assuming a Gaussian distribution, and I would like to code the amplitude spectrum of the beam. What I did, in Matlab, was to create a Gaussian with an average value of 1070 nm and FWHM of 2 nm. Hence I had an $x$ vector with all the wavelengths and an $A$ vector with the corresponding amplitudes.  In order to maintain the total power, I normalized the Gaussian by multiplying for $\sqrt(P)/\sum(A)$.
My idea is that this way by summing all the obtained amplitudes and squaring the sum, I effectively obtain a Gaussian with a total power of 10. The problem is that I'm not entirely sure this normalization is correct. Unfortunately I need to have the amplitude of all the modes, since I'll use them in a following part, therefore I need them to be correctly calculated.
Another suggestion I received was to calculate the area below the Gaussian and make it so that squared it gives $P$, but this seems wrong to me. The modes are discrete, by calculating the area I'm considering contributes that actually don't exist at all. So I wanted to ask which normalization seems more correct to you.
